# $http.get is not giving response

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, get-request

I'm new to node and angular script. I'm having a function readDetails within my service which gives a GET request.

```
this.readDetails = function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/getDetails'
        }).then(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
```

Given below is my server side code.

```
app.get('/getDetails', function(request, response) {
    fs.readFile('details.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        response.send(obj);
        response.end();
    })
})
```

I don't get the response from the server. I do not find Why. Suggestions are welcome

Comment: Whats the response you are getting? Does it fall in the error fallback?

Comment: I'm just guessing here but try `.then(function(response) { return response.data })` instead. I presume you're trying to display the data but instead are resolving your `readDetails` promise with the response object

Comment: ... or even shorter `return $http.get('/getDetails').then(res => res.data)`

Comment: Please show us the code that calls `this.readDetails()` and uses the result.  Are you sure your server-side code is getting called?  Did you add a `.catch()` handler on  your $http call to see if there's an error being returned?  There's lots of debugging you can do on your own here.  And, oh BTW, `if (err) throw err;` is NEVER appropriate error handling in express.